# Trying to pass parameter as binding variable in snowflake statement

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, bind-variables

Below is my stored procedure, I'm not sure as to why it keeps throwing an error. The error I get is

> SQL compilation error: syntax error line XX at position XX unexpected '?'.

I have followed the documentation [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#binding-variables) but it does not seem to work for me.

This is what I have:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE spExample(INPUT_TABLE VARCHAR)
    RETURNS VARCHAR
    LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
    AS
    $$
    result = "";
    try {
        var sql_cmd = "SELECT * FROM ?;";
        var sql_stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: sql_cmd, binds:[INPUT_TABLE]});
        sql_stmt.execute();
    } catch(err) {
        result += "Message: " + err.message;
    }
    return result;
    $$;
```

Have I made a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

Above answers subject your code to sql injection attack. And of course you can bind a table name to a variable in snowflake.

Do
`var sql_cmd = "SELECT * FROM IDENTIFIER('?');";`

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I tried and it executed perfectly:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE spExample(INPUT_TABLE VARCHAR)
    RETURNS VARCHAR
    LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
    AS
    $$
    result = "";
    try {
        var sql_cmd = "SELECT * FROM IDENTIFIER(?);";
        var sql_stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: sql_cmd, binds:[INPUT_TABLE]});
        sql_stmt.execute();
    } catch(err) {
               result += "Message: " + err.message;
    }
    return result;
    $$;
Call spExample('PAIDBILLS');
```

Comment: This works for me too, although not with MERGE statement , it seems.
I do the same "MERGE INTO IDENTIFIER(?) tgt USING () as src ON src.ID = tgt.ID ..."

Answer (score 0):

For me, this worked, first Quotes then brackets. I think its different for different type of query , other answers  worked for me for select but not for SHOW

> `var sql_cmd = "SHOW WAREHOUSES like '(?)';"`

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE spExample(INPUT_TABLE VARCHAR)
RETURNS varchar
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
execute as owner
AS
$$
result = "";
try {
    var sql_cmd = "SHOW WAREHOUSES like '(?)';";
    var sql_stmt = snowflake.execute({sqlText: sql_cmd, binds:[INPUT_TABLE]});
} catch(err) {
           result += "Message: " + err.message;
}
return result;
$$;

Call spExample('WREHOUSE NAME');
```

Answer (score -1):

actually yes.

Bind variable is just that, a variable. So you can do a

`SELECT * FRMO MY_TABLE WHERE MY_COLUMN=?`

but you can't use bind to substitute for commands or column or table names. You can however use simple JS concatenation, like

`var sql_cmd = "SELECT * FROM "+INPUT_TABLE;`

Comment: You're right. I can simply use concatenation but that's the alternative for me. If you scroll down to "right-bind" in the [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#binding-variables) you can see they are also passing a parameter as a bind variable. I have this working for my another stored procedure but it doesn't work here. I find that very odd.

Comment: err, sorry, can you please copypaste the example? because I found the right-bind, and what they are passing is timestamp value that needs conversion.....

Comment: Okay this makes sense. I went back and looked at the example that works and it's not a column name or a table name I'm passing. You're right it works for everything else expect for column or table names. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

It seems I had the exact same misunderstanding as the OP. It was good to find this answer.

In any case, it's a lot more flexible & more readable to use JavaScript template literals using backticks (instead of using single quotes or double quotes). They allow you to use expression interpolation in the format of

```js
`Some text here. ${expression} Some more text here.`
```

Just fill in with your variable or variables (or expression).

Comment: This is a very bad practice, You should never create an SQL strings dynamically. Use parameters instead as OP asked.

Comment: THIS IS WRONG. NEVER EVER DO THIS UNDER ANY CIRCUMSTANCES! In case you've never seen it before please reference Bobby Tables: https://xkcd.com/327